# EF Core - eager loading of related entities

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm obviously missing something when I'm trying to load related entities.

I have 2 related classes:

```
 public class Parcel
    {
        public Guid ParcelId { get; set; }
        public Guid BagId { get; set; }

    }

  public class Bag
    {
        public Guid BagId { get; set; }
        public List<Parcel> Parcels { get; set; }
    }
```

In DbContext's OnModelCreating method:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Bag>().HasKey(x => x.BagId);
 modelBuilder.Entity<Bag>().HasMany<Parcel>();
 modelBuilder.Entity<Parcel>().HasKey(x => x.ParcelId);
```

When I'm querying Bags with `dbContext.Bags.Include(x=>x.Parcels)` it throws an exception saying "Invalid column name 'BagId1'"

I've tried to add a foreign key attribute, didn't help.

```
   [ForeignKey("BagId")]
   public List<Parcel> Parcels { get; set; }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF Core 2.0 migration - Many-to-Many with additional fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469730/ef-core-2-0-migration-many-to-many-with-additional-fields)

Comment: Take a look at the answer from the above link. The problem is the misconfiguration - `modelBuilder.Entity<Bag>().HasMany<Parcel>();` should be `modelBuilder.Entity<Bag>().HasMany(x => x.Parcels);` Or remove the whole shown fluent API configuration because all what you are trying to setup is the EF Core conventional default.

Comment: Duh. Simple. Thank you!